# Azure AD Connect "Unable to validate credentials"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am working on a already functioning Azure Ad Connect VM, it syncs and the proxy connection responds with the code 200.
BUT whenever i want to sign in, in the AAD connect in my VM, with my admin Account, i get this error.
"Unable to validade credentials due to an expected error. Restart Azure AD Connect with th/ InteractiveAuth Option to further diagnose this issue."

Any idea what must cause this? I have tried every forum idea i could find with no answer. OH and upgrading is also no idea since to upgrade i need to SIGN IN also...which i can´t.

Thanks!

Comment: have you referred this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/tshoot-connect-connectivity#troubleshooting-steps-for-previous-releases

Comment: Yes i did, and it passed the tests.

Comment: Can you please confirm me if you are using your domain emailid ( user@activedirectorydomainname.onmicrosoft.com or your organization account .) to signin and not any other emailid's ?

Comment: The program was probably bugged. This was the solution provided by a microsoft agent.                                                                                                                                   Navigate to “C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect” directory on the server system where AD Connect is installed.

Copy the path.

Open command prompt and change directory to “C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect”

At the prompt, type /AzureADConnect.exe /InteractiveAuth and hit the Enter key

Comment: After that i could login using the same account, upgrade de ADDC and the problem was gone. Thanks anyway to everyone who commented to help!

Comment: Thank you , I have posted the above solution as answer for future reference of community members .

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to resolve the issue:**

- Navigate to directory on the server where AD Connect is
  installed and copy the path (“C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory
  Connect”).
- Open command prompt and change directory to the above copied path.
- Type and run /AzureADConnect.exe /InteractiveAuth in the prompt.
- After you have performed the above steps, login using the same account and upgrade the Azure AD Domain Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command in cmd (Command Prompt) and login to account.

It will open AAD Client Connect login dialog with GUI

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect\AzureADConnect.exe" /interactiveauth
```